# Allocating an array of a class c++

Tags: c++

How would I go about allocating an array of a class without constructing the class, so I could fill up the array later?

I was originally trying to use

```
Myclass * array = new Myclass[N];
```

But it tries to construct Myclass to N.

Comment: One option is to use [placement `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I was going to suggest that in an answer. Perhaps you would like to do that.

Comment: `std::vector` with `reserve()` and `emplace_back()` obsolete the placement `new` approach as of C++11, guys. I've added that solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First just declare it without allocating

```
Myclass * array[N];
```

when you need it

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
 array[i] = new Myclass(/*params*/);
}
```

But consider using `std::vector/std::list` if you must not have to manage memory yourself.

Comment: This is an array of pointers, not an array of Myclass. (But it may be useful for OP anyway).

Comment: Yes it's that. "pointer to Myclass" is not the same as "Myclass" however.

Comment: In fact, with your solution it is `std::unique_ptr` to use to avoid memory management (as the array itself is not allocated).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, (not sure why), you could try

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
 public:
  MyClass()
  { cout << "helo" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int size = 4;

  // Here is the trick, pointer to pointer.
  MyClass **vec = new MyClass *[size];

  cout << "before" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    vec[i] = new MyClass;

  // remember to free the vec
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested placement new, so here it goes:

```
// allocate space
    std::vector<unsigned char> mybuffer(N * sizeof(Myclass));
    Myclass *array = reinterpret_cast<Myclass *>(&mybuffer[0]);

// when you're ready to use it
    new( &array[0] ) Myclass(2);
    new( &array[1] ) Myclass(3);
    // etc...

// when you're done with it
    array[0].~Myclass();
    array[1].~Myclass();
    // etc....
```

Of course, it is undefined behaviour to use `array[x]` before you have `new`'d it, or after you called the destructor.

This is generally something you wouldn't use as a solution to a "normal" problem. Consider actually defining a default constructor that does nothing, and having a function you call later which enhances the objects above their default state.

Comment: You should take attention to the alignment of your buffer.

Comment: The default allocator calls `::operator new()`, which allocates memory that is aligned for any type

Comment: `MyClass` may have stronger alignment requirement.

Comment: `MyClass` is a type, so it cannot have a stronger alignment requirement than "any type".

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11, the optimal solution for you is probably `std::vector<MyClass>` with `emplace`-base insertions:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass(int a, bool b, char c); // some non-default constructor
  MyClass(double d);              // another constructor
  void bar();
};

void foo(int n) {
  std::vector<MyClass> mv;
  mv.reserve(n);    // not even needed but beneficial if you know the final size.

  // emplace_back uses perfect forwarding to call any arbitrary constructor:
  mv.emplace_back(2, false, 'a');
  mv.emplace_back(3, true,  'b');
  mv.emplace_back(3.1415926535);

  // can iterate vector easily:
  for (auto &i : mv) {
    i.bar();
  }

  // everything destructed automatically when the collection falls of scope ...
}
```

This creates the values in the collection directly without a copy and defers any construction of elements until you are ready, unlike `new[]`, which makes a bunch of default objects at array-creation time. It is generally better than placement `new` as well, since it doesn't leave open opportunities for missed destruction or destructing an invalid memory location as well as being just easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may use [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

So in your case:

```
std::vector<boost::optional<Myclass>> array(N);
```